# How to create a symbolic link of all files in a directory using a shortened name obtained with using a piped cut on the filename

Tags: find, symlink, libraries

I have a directory full of libraries (`*.so.0.*`), and I want to use `find` to create a symbolic link to each file, named `*.so.0`.

Here is a (non working) try:

`find $HOME/.local/lib64/ -name "lib*.so.0.*" -execdir ln -s {} $(echo {} | cut -d . -f 1-4) \;`

But I cannot find why it doesn't work.

I tried with only one library, using `ln -s ./libfoo.so.0.12.0. $(echo ./libfoo.so.0.12.0. | cut -d . -f 1-4)`, the result being `./libfoo.so.0`.

Comment: Have you considered simply linking to the directory, as opposed to the files themselves? Depending on whether this suffices for your purposes, it removes the need for the use of find and you can simply link the directory.

Comment: Why don't you just `cd` to that dir and `for f in lib*.so.0.*; do echo ln -s "$f" "${f%%.*}.so.0"; done` (remove the echo if OK) ?

Comment: - @tniles09 I want to execute a program that need the library named like this, $HOME/.local/lib64/ being inside LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  

- @don_crissti It seems to work, but I will probably have to do the command for multiple directories, as all these lib aren't directly inside $HOME/.local/lib64/ (some being in sub-directories). Moreover, I'll soon have to evolve this command in order to make it works for `$HOME/.local/lib64/` and `$HOME/.local/lib32/`.  

- @drg `ln: failed to create symbolic link '$(echo ./libfoo.so.0.12.0. | cut -d . -f 1-4)': No such file or directory`

Comment: I've found my answer here (I did not find it during my previous search) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825393/how-to-use-pipe-within-exec-in-find
Worked with `find $HOME/.local/lib64/ -name 'lib*.so.0.*' -execdir bash -c 'ln -s {} $(echo {} | cut -d . -f 1-4)' \;`

Thank for your help @don_crissti @drg @tniles09

Comment: @don_crissti As you responded my comment with the same suggestion, can you provide it as respond to my question?

Comment: Dremor, I will but what happens if you have `libgoo.so.0.12.0` and `libgoo.so.0.13.1` ? Do you want to `ln -sf` ?

Comment: @Dremor, **NEVER** stuff an arbitrary filename into a shell command.  You've made a security hole *wide open*.  All I have to do is `touch 'lib.so.0. x;rm -rf /*;#'` and your server is gone after you run your `find` command.  (If you self-answer this question I can modify your approach to be safe.)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set up an alternative set of ELF libraries for running an application, so instead of mucking with manually creating the symlinks, go straight to the intended application for the problem: `ldconfig $HOME/.local/lib64/` should update all of the symlinks in the directory for you.

They won't always be `.so.0` either, it will depend on the SOVERSION data in the ELF libraries.